# Can an index column be used in the .loc accessor for pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm a pandas beginner and wanted to know if an index column can be used in the `.loc` accessor in pandas.

Here is code that works.

```py
daus = pd.read_csv("active-users-by-day.csv", parse_dates=['date']) daus.loc[:, 'date']
```

And here is code that triggers an error.

```py
daus = pd.read_csv("active-users-by-day.csv", parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date') daus.loc[:, 'date']
```

I found that the difference is that when I include `index_col = "date"` in the `read_csv` function call then I can't access the date column via the `.loc` accessor. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add images to my question but it didn't work. 

Here is code that works.

`daus = pd.read_csv("active-users-by-day.csv", parse_dates=['date'])
daus.loc[:, 'date']`

And here is code that doesn't work.

`daus = pd.read_csv("active-users-by-day.csv", parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
daus.loc[:, 'date']`

Comment: Don't add images, add some minimal example of the data as **text** with proper formatting

Comment: index is not a column. to access index you may use `df.index`